# 'GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h' file not found

Tags: cocoapods, google-mobile-ads

every thing is uptodate if any one here to help kindly tell me is this the issue with the SDK or I am doing any mistake....

the actually issue is ....

I updated Google AdMob SDK to 8.4.0 using Pods.

So in my appDelegate.m, I am trying to add this line

@import GoogleMobileAds;

But I get error saying Module 'GoogleMobileAds' not found.